# (AVCaptureDevice) Why can't I get my camera device

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturedevice

**I wrote the following code, but I can't get my camera device. It always crash**

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
  fatalError()
}
```

**After I change to the following code, it's work!**

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
   fatalError()
}
```

**Could anyone tell me why? thank you!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code 1 :

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back) else {
  fatalError()
}
```

Here you have used a keyword `builtInDualCamera` which is not available in every Apple device. That's why your application got crashed.

[image]

## Code 2:

```
guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
   fatalError()
}
```

Above code just check that your device having video capturing capacity or not. **I think all devices are having this functionality that's why it is working.**